# ksh script syntax error on date

Tags: unix, ksh

My shell script fails on this portion

```
dt=$(date +%Y%m%d)

syntax error at line 35: `dt=$' unexpected
```

It's a bit strange as I'm using the same to get the datetime and don't get any problem

```
timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)

20170911105251
```

I've checked in Notepad++ as well that I don't have any dirty characters as suggested by @Frank below

[image]

Below is the sample script I have. Please note I have omitted some portions that are confidential. Basically the script transfers files from Server A to B based on the dt specified. If no date parameter is specified during execution, it takes the current date.

```
if [ -z "$1" ]
then
    dt=$(date +%Y%m%d)
else
    dt=$1
fi

export rundate

timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)
logfile=${log_path}/${batch}-${dt}-${timestamp}.log
mail_file=${log_path}/${batch}-mail-${timestamp}.txt

export mail_file

filecount=$(wc -l ${batch_filelist} | cut -d " " -f 1)

sftp ${dest} <<EOF >> $logfile
cd $destdir
lcd $sourcedir
put -p *.txt
exit
EOF


mail -s "SFTP Done (dt:$dt)" $(cat $email_accounts) < $mail_file
```

Comment: I see from your screenshot that you're trying to run a command named `dt`: `dt=$(dt ...` -- that doesn't explain the error message though. Are you sure you're showing line 35?

Comment: @glennjackman - the initial post contained only a portion of my script. I have included the whole thing for clarity.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a working example

Comment: Still, you are attempting to call a command `dt`

Comment: At beginning of question you state `dt=$(date +%Y%m%d)` is causing a problem ... notice reference to **date**; but this piece of code does not exist in your full script; in your full script you have `dt=$(dt +%Y%m%d)` ... notice reference to **dt** instead of **date**; unless the `dt` (on the right side) is a user-defined alias/functiion/script this is going to cause an error (eg, `dt` is an invalid command); consider changing this command to `dt=$(date ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Becarful , when you copy text from anywhere and paste in file (i think you did it) , it can add "dirty" characters . 
If you have a text editor like notepad++ , by clicking on :

[image]

It will show all characters .

Via notepad++ you can change the file format from windows to unix , by right click on bottom-right in page :

[image]

Save the file and send again in to your machine .
The syntax seems correct so it should work .

Anyway i mentioned notepad++ but you can do this with other text editors.

`dt=$(date +'%Y%m%d')` and **not** `dt=$(dt +'%Y%m%d')`

A working example below :

```
!/usr/bin/bash
if [ -z $1 ]
then
    dt=$(date +'%Y%m%d')
else
    dt=$1
fi
echo $dt
```

Result :

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:/pathtosh> prova.sh

20170911

xxxxxxxxxxxxxx:/pathtosh> prova.sh 1

1

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually checked this already and there's not dirty characters (must have happened when I was composing my question above.)

Comment: corrected my post as I was changing the variable names from my original script. Is my understanding correct that I should put the %Y%m%d in single quotes? Does that apply to the timestamp variable as well?

Comment: it works without single quotes too , your problem its beyond from syntax

Comment: I've modified my syntax to the legacy one which is dt=`date +%Y%m%d` and finally works. Really strange behavior from my client's server.

Comment: If the answer was useful for you ,would be kind if you accept :)